# Request size limit when sending through HttpClient in Google Appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, apache-httpclient-4.x

Is there any request size limit when sending through socket (using HttpClient) in Google Appengine?

I am getting following exception when sending more than 1MB of data in GAE.

"The request to API call remote_socket.Send() was too large."

Our App Engine is Billed one. I am sure that our data doesn't exceed any limit like 113MB per minute in [Quotas](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Sockets)

I searched in Google but couldn't find any solution. Is there any other limit I need to know?

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ? I'm having the same with with AppEngine.

Comment: Can you share some code samples or explain more about what exactly are you trying to accomplish ? I had a similar issue sending large amount of data to Google Cloud SQL and got it working finally.

Comment: Hi Raghvendra, Thanks for your concern. I'm trying to send bulk emails to third party emails services as POST data using HTTP Client. When post data exceeded 1MB, it is throwing exception. In exception,, I'm trying send normally in Java